# appended data from an AJAX result wont execute another jQuery function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

basically, im trying to create a facebook/twitter like news feed, where i display a minimum of 3 latest post only from the database.

on the bottom of the post, i have a clickable div for `load more posts..`

upon clicking the div, of course it displays the another 3 old posts and so on..

currently, i have 15 posts in my database, it is displayed as followed (id 15 as the recently added post)

```
id:15 - some posts - some comments
id:14 - some posts - some comments
id:13 - some posts - some comments

load more...
```

above will display the **posts** and the associated **comments** per posts.

```
<ul id="post">
    <?php while.. { ?>
    <li><?php echo id; ?> - <?php echo posts; ?> </li>
         <ul id="comments">
            <?php while .. {?>
            <li> <?php echo comments; ?> </li>
            <?php } //end while ?>
         </ul>
    <?php } //end of while?>
</ul>
<span last_id="<?php echo id?>"> Load More ... </span>
```

you can also see my `<span>` tag, which displays the last ID (13) of the result. which will then be handled by my jQuery below.

this the jQuery for the `<span>` tag, when this is clicked, it will get the last post id (13), and use that last ID value to get another set of 3 old post `12`, `11`, `10`

```
$(function() {
    $('.loadmore').click(function () {
        var last_id = $(this).attr('last_id');
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"../portal/includes/get_posts.php",
            data: "last_id="+last_id,
            success: function(html) {
            $('#post').append(html);
        }
        });
    return false; 
    });
});
```

the fetched value will append to my `<ul id="post">` resulting to this format

```
id:15 - some posts - some comments
id:14 - some posts - some comments
id:13 - some posts - some comments
id:12 - some posts - some comments
id:11 - some posts - some comments
id:10 - some posts - some comments

load more...
```

but when i click the `load more...` again, it wont query for another set of 3 old posts.

it appears, that my jQuery cannot recognize the appended.

how can i resolve this?

thanks.

Comment: $('.post')... is searching a class, did you try $('#post').append(html);

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ should solve your issue

Comment: dynamically loaded content needs event delegation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be a problem with event, you need to use event binding, if you want to manipulate with ajax loaded content. So, change this:
`$('.loadmore').click(function () {`
to this:
`$(document).on('click', '.loadmore', function () {`

Comment: Thank you for this! id buy you a beer if i could! 'm glad you understood my post. i thought i was too vague

Answer (score 0):

You should have a class on that span:

```
<span class="loadmore" data-last_id="<?php echo id?>">
```

Which, as has been pointed out should be used in jQuery like:

```
$(document).on('click', '.loadmore', function () {
  //
});
```

And `$('.post').append(html);` should be `$('#post').append(html);`

I would also consider changing the `last-id` attribute to a more friendly data attribute:

```
<span data-last_id="<?php echo id?>">
```

which would be picked up with jQuery:

```
var last_id = $(this).data('last_id');
```

Comment: hi Andy, yea, thanks for pointing my error. but the main issue im having is how to execute the same AJAX function from the appended data.

Comment: I think you're missing a class on that `span` too...